# NSString in settings bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to implement a text field in settings.app for my application and save the value as an NSString to called on later within my app. I can't find an example of doing something this simple, all the answers on google call for creating an entire array but I simply want to save a single string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read the documentation about the [`NSUserDefaults` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use NSUserDefaults to pull anything from the settings app.
The settings app works with a plist which can contain arrays.
The arrays are used if you want to set items in a group.

If you just want to have a string in your settings app, then you will need to put it into an array so that the settings app can set an identifier to it that you can call in your code.

You can just use strings by themselves, but they do not appear in the settings app.

So the simplest thing to do is this:

[image: Settings Plist]

You can see that the Root of the settings (or this case any PList) is an array, which then contain a dictionary.

Within that you will see that it contains 3 string - these are for:

1) the default value of the string (This is what the user can change

2) The key is so that you can work with it inside your code and reference to it.

3) and the 3rd one is to specify for the settings app what type it needs to display.

Then when that is all done you can use:

```
_buttonSelection = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"buttonAction01"]; //_buttonSelection is a NSString so that can be anything
```

This way the user can change the value and you can take that value to use in your program.

I know it is not as simple as you would have liked, but I hope you now understand why it is setup the way that it is.

Good Luck:-)

Comment: would you want to make a new plist for this or can you simply use the existing app plist?

Comment: You can use the existing one - The settings app will use the Root.plist - If you do not want the user to be able to change in the settings, but inside the app it self you can just provide them with a UITextField somewhere. However the structure still stands as you will need to refer to it from your app.